# Simple Text Editor for Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, text-editor, debian

## Issue

Leafpad is the default text editor for the LXDE Desktop environment designed to be lightweight and simple. Although I like this design choice, there are some additional features available in other text editors (ex: Notepad++ for Windows) that indeed improve productivity:
*in order of importance*

- *spell checker
- *macro: simple rec/play keystrokes
- *info bar: total characters/lines and current position
- bracket matching
- multi-tab
- auto-completion
- syntax highlighting
- code folding

*(*) indispensable*

**Question**
Is there another text editor for Linux still lightweight and simple to use but with the aforementioned features (specially the indispensable ones)?

---

## Follow up

### Mousepad Editor

Following some advices, I've just installed mousepad and it seems that it has only benefits compared to leafpad:

- very easy installation (just `apt install mousepad`)
- lightweight: no need to bloat the lxde install with gnome/kde dependencies
- simple, easy and fast
- built-in (no need to install plugins): status bar, bracket matching, multi-tab, syntax highlighting

However, it doesn't solve completely the original issue since there are still some missing features:

- *spell checker
- *keystrokes macro
- auto-completion
- code folding

---

**Operating System**

- Debian Strech with LXDE
  [debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso)

Comment: Let me know how to migrate the original post from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461463/simple-text-editor-for-desktop-environment) to Software Recommendations.

Comment: On my Linux box I use xed (xedit) when using a graphical text editor. Has spell checking, but lacks macros and total characters from your must-haves. I found no bracket matching either, nor auto-complete. Syntax highlighting is there, but no code folding. // PS: consider posting your answer as answer, not part of the question ;) // as for migrating that post: too late, you've already posted the same here so it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @izzy _"I use xed (xedit)"_ Its not very user friendly, ex: seems that to open a file it is necessary to write the filename instead of browsing.

Comment: @Izzy _"PS: consider posting your answer as answer, not part of the question ;)"_ Agree, as soon as I get an answer. Mousepad is just a workaround. It is very painful to not have spell checker.

Comment: @Izzy _"too late, you've already posted the same here so it would be a duplicate."_ 1) Mind to explain what should I have done? 2) Since there was no answer at Unix & Linux, I've tried to get such migration answer here. Should I delete the [ON HOLD] questions at Unix & Linux?

Comment: "necessary to write the filename": Nope. A file picker opens. // "Post answer": Yesplease. List how it matches and fails to match your requirements, and it should be fine. // Migration: 1) instead of reposting, flag it for mod attention, asking to migrate. Mods can do that. OR repost it if you know mods won't do or take too long. But never do both (except if mods decline your request). 2) I'd do so, yes. They are not of much use there – except acting as a signpost to others, saying "this kind of question is not welcome here". But then, who checks that?

Comment: As a feature, I often find "column mode to be very helpful

Comment: Have you looked at vim or emacs?  Neither of them is particularly _easy_ to learn, but they both have GUI versions, and cover all of your requirements either directly, or via plugins or scripts.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn _"Have you looked at vim or emacs?"_ Yes, I'm aware that they are very powerful yet lightweight. However, as you've mentioned, learning their interface is long process. Therefore, I prefer not including them on this list.

Answer (score 2):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (free) has these features. Consider it as lightweight one.

- spell checker: plugin **Spell Checker**
- macro: plugin **Macros**
- info bar: statusbar, and it can be customized by "ui_statusbar_" options
- bracket matching: plugin **Hilite Brackets**
- multi-tab: tabs UI is the default
- auto-completion: plugins, e.g. **HTML Completion**
- syntax highlighting: in preinstalled "lexers"
- code folding: in preinstalled "lexers"

Comment: Seems to be a powerful yet lightweight (14MiB) text editor. Any idea why it is not available at Debian repo?

Comment: @MarkMessa What is "Debian repo", some software site? So they didn't add this app.

Comment: @MarkMessa Likely because it's written in Delphi, which is not exactly well supported on almost any Linux platform.

Comment: @RProgram https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Comment: And is so easy to add your own plugins

Answer (score 2):

### Geany:

✓ Lightweight and superfast
✓ Spell check ([plugin](https://plugins.geany.org/spellcheck.html))
✓ Macro ([plugin](https://plugins.geany.org/geanymacro.html))
✓ info bar: total characters/lines and current position
✓ bracket matching
✓ multi-tab
✓ auto-completion
✓ syntax highlighting
✓ code folding

It even has some basic build/execute tools to check your code directly.

Comment: It seems to be much more than a simple text editor yet still lightweight (10Mb): project management, embedded terminal emulator, basic IDE, ...

Comment: Another very happy Geany user here... seems very light, but as noted, has some basic IDE features.  Only thing I'm really missing is good `git` integration.  But since there is a command line window/view in the editor, I can get by...

Answer (score 1):

#### [Textadept](https://orbitalquark.github.io/textadept/)

Textadept is a lite (3.9Mb download for Linux), actively developed, cross-platform (I've used it for years on Win, Ubuntu/Mint, and OSX), very fast (starts up very quickly, which was the reason I first started using it), Scintilla-based text editor. Or, in the words of the developer, Textadept is

> A fast, minimalist, and remarkably extensible cross-platform text editor

It has *many* features beyond those required by OP (see its [website landing page](https://orbitalquark.github.io/textadept/) for a quick overview), but also those stipulated above:

- [image: Yes] *spell checker | via add-on [Spellcheck module](https://foicica.com/wiki/spellcheck)
- [image: Yes] *macro: simple rec/play keystrokes |  via add-on [Macro module](https://foicica.com/wiki/macro)
- [image: Yes] *info bar: total characters/lines and current position | yep
- [image: Yes] bracket matching | natively
- [image: Yes] multi-tab | natively
- [image: Yes] auto-completion | natively
- [image: Yes] syntax highlighting | natively
- [image: Note] code folding | yes, but [depends on the "lexer"](https://foicica.com/textadept/manual.html#Code.Folding)

Basic screenshot (showing "split screen" feature -- note that Textadept is "themable"):

[image: textadep]
<sub>(source: [foicica.com](https://foicica.com/textadept/images/splitviews.png))</sub>

Sweet and simple. It has been my first-choice "basic" text editor for many years now.

Comment: P.s. I use one of the Base16 themes provided by [Robert Gieseke](https://github.com/rgieseke/textadept-themes). Something there for every taste!